# body 100% height of document

Tags: css, height

If you scroll down on that test page you can see where my struggle is:

http://new.los-chaos.ch/

The body has 100% height, and should therfore get the documents 100% height.
But the Body only gehts the viewports 100% height, instead of the document 100% height.

The page should every time contain 100% document height.

The document height should be at least every time the viewport height.

There should no space at the top or bottom of the page.

I don't get why it only gets 100% viewport height right now..

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change body's css to:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

This will ensure that the body is atleast equal to the viewport's height. Else, it will be the height of the content it contains.

Comment: this worked. i didnt know about the "100vh" - thanks!

Comment: Ha ha... Quick Fix. But supported only for modern browsers. `:(`

Comment: on this page there is no need to support old browsers, so this soluton is perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

Add height 100% onto body and html. Then remove height 100% from your main_wrapper

```
body, html{
  height:100%;
}
main_wrapper{
  //height:100%;
}
```

Comment: this does not work, becouse the content will the be merged be the contents height. so if there is not as many content as the viewport height it will get smaller